# context.become changes the behaviour of Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm learning how to use context.become to control the state of my actor, i'm using this code:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
     println("Happens here")
     active(Set.empty)
   }

  def active(isInSet: Set[String]): Receive = {
    case Add(key) =>
      context.become(active(isInSet+key))
    case Contains(key) =>
      sender() ! isInSet(key)
    case ShowAll =>
      println(isInSet.toSeq)
  }

}

case class Add(key: String)
case class Contains(key: String)
object ShowAll


object DemoBecome extends App{

override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 val system = ActorSystem("BecomeUnbecome")
 val act = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor]), "demoActor")

 act ! Add("1")
 act ! ShowAll
 act ! Add("2")
 act ! ShowAll

 Thread.sleep(10000)
 System.exit(0)

}
```

When i send the first message, the "receive" works and prints the message, after the second message doesn't show, this is my output:

```
Happens here
Set()
Vector(1)
Set(1)
Vector(1, 2)
```

If i change the receive method, for this:

```
def receive = {
  case a: Add => println("happens here Add" )
  case c: Contains => println("happens here Contains")
  case ShowAll => println("happens here Show")
}
```

I receive this output:

```
happens here Add
happens here Show
happens here Add
happens here Show
```

So i tried, to track the moment when "receive" is "blocked", but i didn't have success, my doubt is: When i uses context.become in my actor, how and when Akka handle the messages after the first one?

Comment: This is not what I get: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6IdNU8IUTQyj4ZEmyZGStg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `context.become` you are changing the behavior in your actor. That means, when the actor starts it using the default `receive` behavior. However, when it receives a message it prints the message `Happens here` and uses the partial function `active` to handle it.

Since, inside `active` you call `context.become(active(_))` the behavior of the actor changes. From now on, when a messages gets sent to the actor it will execute the partial function `active` instead of the `receive` method and that's why you are not seeing `Happens here` more than once in your output.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanantion! Follow up question - So how can we change the behaviour such that receive is called again in subsequent messages of the actor?

Comment: you can use `context.unbecome` or call again `contest.become(receive)`. For the second option you need to be careful since you could be leaking resources. The official docs explains all this really well: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#become-unbecome